# App crash when I try send SMS

Tags: android, sms, kotlin

I try to send SMS in kotlin, I wrote simple app with the following code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val textView = findViewById(R.id.mainTextView) as TextView
    SEND.setOnClickListener {
        textView.setText("click")
        val sm = SmsManager.getDefault()
        sm.sendTextMessage("123123123", null, "test", null, null)
        textView.setText("OK")

    }
  }
}
```

When I try run app via USB cable from AndroidStudio app don't want permissions despite the fact I've added permission SEND_SMS to manifest. When I push button app closes

Comment: Post the logcat?

Comment: did you add run time permission if you are running your app fro android version>=23

Answer (score 1):

you have to request the permission by yourself. 
As described in this [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use run time permissions set target SDK version to 21 in your Gradle.

Add **target SDK** in your **Gradle** like this:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        .....
        .....
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }
}
```